# Form Closing when I press "c" when focus is on Radio Button or Check Box

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Form is closing when I press "c" when the focus is on the radio button or checkbox.

In the below form I have two buttons which named as Ok and Cancel(with Shortcut as "c") and two radio buttons. When I put the focus on radio button and press "c", the form is closing.

Once I press "c" in the form level, the btncancel_Clik event is firing and closing the form.

I even verified in by creating a sample app there also I observed the same behavior that is closing the form.

I'd like to know if there is any way we can handle this.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The way it works is the way it's supposed to work. It's not a good idea to not follow conventions, so I suggest you stick to this.

Comment: What code is for cancel button.?

Comment: Yes, when I remove shortcut of  "c" for that button is not closing the form.

Comment: @Peter its just this.close().

Comment: That will close the form.if you shotcut C is meant for something else its firing the same as the button.you need to change that.

Comment: if I change to another shortcut key, what if I press the same key what I have given. again it would be the same behavior. isn't it.

Comment: If you remove the `C` shortcut from the Cancel button, does the behaviour stop?

Comment: Yes, @mjwills. it will not close

Answer (score 0):

Check This Code:

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.C && radioButton1.Focused == true) {
    this.Close();
}
```